# I am getting a parsing error

Tags: php

```
<?php if($this->cart->contents()): ?>
  <form method="post" action="cart/process">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <tr>
        <th>Quanity</th>
        <th>Item Title</th>
        <th style="text-align:right">Item Price</th>
      </tr>
      <?php $i = 0; ?>
      <?php foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items): ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo  $items['qty']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo  $items['name']; ?></td>
          <td style="text-align:right"><?php echo $this->cart->format_number($items['price']); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_name['.$i.']" value="'.$items['name'].'"  />';?>
        <?php echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_code['.$i.']" value="'.$items['id'].'"  />';?>
        <?php echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_qty['.$i.']" value="'.$items['qty'].'"  />';?>
      <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="right"><strong>Shipping</strong></td>
      <td class="right" style="text-align:right"><?php echo $this->config->item('shipping');?> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="right"><strong>Tax</strong></td>
      <td class="right" style="text-align:right"><?php echo $this->config->item('tax');?> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="right"><strong>Total</strong></td>
      <td class="right" style="text-align:right"><strong>$<?php echo $this->cart->format_number($this->cart_total() + $this-config->item('total'));?></strong> </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <?php if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) :?>
    <p><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>users/register"</p>
    <p><em>You must log in to make purchases</em></p>
  <?php else :?>
    <h3>Shipping Information</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Address</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Address 2</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address2" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>City</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>State</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="state" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Zipcode</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="zipcode" />
    </div>
    <p><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">Checkout</button></p>
  <?php endif; ?>
  </form>
<?php else :?>
  <p>There are no items in your cart</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The following is the error that I get:
Severity: Parsing Error
Message: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)
Filename: views/cart.php
Line Number: 34
I have search in line 34, where the syntax word of "total" is located but cannot find the error. I have pasted the whole code that I am having trouble with.

Comment: You are missing an `>` on line 34. Change ` $this-config->item('total')` to ` $this->config->item('total')`

Comment: Thank you. You were correct. working fine now.